# Quake - commands to disable graphic components

Tags: quake

What is the console command for disabling / limiting drawn particles and disabling dynamic lighting in Quake 1, please?

Comment: Did the original Quake feature dynamic lighting? Or are you talking about one its many [ports](https://quake.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Quake_Source_ports)?